# entity framework code-first database loss of non-english characters after seed from csv file

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am populating a database from a CSV file using `Seed()` function. However, when doing this I have lost all Non-English characters. They are replaced with � char.

For example, in the CSV file I have "łódzkie" and in my database its "��dzkie".
CSV is saved with UTF-8 encoding. On `connectionString` I have included `charset=utf8`.

Here is part of Seed() function:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string resourceName = "FirstNames.csv";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
        csvReader.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
        csvReader.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
        var firstNames = csvReader.GetRecords<FirstName>().ToArray();
        context.FirstNames.AddOrUpdate(f => f.Name, firstNames);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, if possible, could you please provide with the csv file ?

Comment: Perhaps, this will help https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1010230/Special-Characters-are-getting-converted-to-on-imp

Comment: Which is datatype of the column you try to insert data in?

Comment: @PajriAprilio here is csv file https://github.com/ogigg/RandomDataWeb/blob/master/RandomDataWeb/Models/SeedData/States.csv

Comment: @DenisRubashkin string

Comment: `string` isn't a SQL Server datatype.  I think the question is leading towards does the data go into a `VARCHAR` or an `NVARCHAR` column?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin NVARCHAR

Comment: Just to be sure: are the characters really replaced, or are they merely *displayed* like that in whatever UI you use to check?

Comment: @GertArnold All non-english chars are replaced in database. I checked it in Microsoft SQL server

Comment: check the SQL DB or table collation

Comment: @viveknuna collation is Polish_CI_AS on database and tables so it should work perfectly fine with polish chars

Comment: Hi @Ogig , what library do you use to read the csv file ? I mean the CsvReader.

Comment: Hi all. I managed to fix this issue. The problem was in CsvReader in line  `using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))`
I have changed Encoding from `UTF8` to `Default` and problem was gone. Thanks for help @PajriAprilio

Comment: Glad to hear that. I was trying to replicate the issue, but got error on CsvReader.